# SSIS Scheduled Job with ODBC fails

Tags: sql-server, oracle, ssis, odbc, oledb

I am running Microsoft SQL Server 2005 - 9.00.4060.00 (Intel X86) on a Windows Server 2003 Enterprise Edition SP2. Oracle Installed is of 11g Release 1 (11.1) for Microsoft Windows (32-Bit).

I am importing data from an Oracle database using the Native Oledb\Microsoft Oledb Provider for Oracle. I can successfully run the package directly in SSBIDS but when I try and run it as a job I get the below error:

**Message
Executed as user: AMERICAS\processamcwindows. ...5.00 for 32-bit  Copyright (C) Microsoft Corp 1984-2005. All rights reserved.    Started:  6:24:10 AM  Error: 2013-09-06 06:24:12.85     Code: 0xC0202009     Source: RSDomsStatus Connection manager "UDM"     Description: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80004005.  An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft OLE DB Provider for ODBC Drivers"  Hresult: 0x80004005  Description: "[Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified".  End Error  Error: 2013-09-06 06:24:12.86     Code: 0xC00291EC     Source: Execute SQL Task - Check and Create the Temp table in Oracle 1 Execute SQL Task     Description: Failed to acquire connection "UDM". Connection may not be configured correctly or you may not have the right permissions on this connection.  End Error  DTExec: The package execution returned DTSER_FAILURE (1).  Started:  6:2...  The package execution fa...  The step failed.**

I am not finding any clear direction on where else to go for this problem. Any advise would be appreciated.

Comment: Your SQL Server could stand to be patched. http://sqlserverbuilds.blogspot.com Is the SSIS job step using the credentials of the account running SQL Agent or have you created an authorized credential to run SSIS? Whatever account executes the package, is *it* able to connect to the Oracle instance?

Comment: It's a legacy application. So patching is not an option and the application will be decommissioned in coming few months so we are on exception waiver. But does the patching helps in solving the problem?
The SSIS package is run through "Sql Agent Service Account" , no proxy was created for this. I am not sure if this account has the required privileges to log into Oracle Db. But the same account is accessing the Sql Server db (connection manager used - .net provider\sqlclient data provider) without any issues.

Comment: Tried creating a credential , then proxy and assigned it to Job step.
Ran the job but got a different error this time related to the proxy created. Error:
Message
Unable to start execution of step 1 (reason: Error authenticating proxy NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM, system error: Logon failure: unknown user name or bad password.).  The step failed.
I may sound dumb as I am trying the proxy thing first time. Any type   of help is much appreciated.

Comment: @billinkc :
Created a proxy based on the inputs from the blog 
http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/e13c137c-1535-4475-8c2f-c7e6e7d125fc/how-do-i-troubleshoot-ssis-packages-failed-execution-in-a-sql-agent-job.
Ran the job which invokes the ssis package. Got the below error (which is same as the previous one):
Message
Executed as user: AMERICAS\Abhishek_Chakrabort1. (-- only difference it got executed by the proxy name).

Comment: @billinkc -- 
The issue solved , changed the connection manager to ADO.NET instead of OLEDB and used linked server connection wherever needed.